# Converting numpy datetime64 to long integer and back

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

How to convert NumPy datetime64 to a long ineteger and back?

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now()).astype(long)
```

Gives a value of 1511975032478959

```
np.datetime64(np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now()).astype(long))
```

Gives an error:

```
ValueError: Converting an integer to a NumPy datetime requires a specified unit
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to specify the units of the long int (in this case, microseconds).

```
 np.datetime64(np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now()).astype(long), 'us')
```

returns

```
 numpy.datetime64('2017-11-29T17:11:44.638713')
```

Comment: I figured that by adding 'us' as the second parameter. But anyway. Thank you.

Comment: NameError: name 'long' is not defined

Answer (score 4):

'us' converts to microseconds. If you require a different format use:
[image]

as shown [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Python3 (other answers seem to focus in Python2):

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
np.datetime64(int(now),'s')
```

2022-07-01T14:25:22